# Problem with PDO WHERE when using VARCHAR-columns in SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

We are upgrading our MS SQL Server from SQL Server 2012 to the current version.
We are using PDO with M$ ODBC driver running on CentOS Linux. PHP version is 7.4.

The problem is that if there is a (prepared) condition like

```
WHERE variable = ?
```

and variable is of type VARCHAR there comes an error

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The data types varchar and text are incompatible in the equal to operator
```

An example code is like this:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE user_login = ? AND user_application  = ?");
$stmt->execute([$login, $app]);
```

user_login and user_application are both VARCHAR-columns and $login and $app normal PHP string variables.

It wasn't a problem with the previous SQL server, the comparison went OK. I don't want to go through all the codebase to circumvent this in myriads of places - so - is there some setting somewhere (SQL server, ODBC-driver, PHP config, ...) where to set things "right" again?

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68646773/edit) your question to show some example code that demonstrates the issue, including the calls to `prepare` and `bindValue`.

Comment: Added the example code...

Comment: It might be worth trying the SQLSRV driver. It will still use your ODBC driver underneath but perhaps it handles types differently.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to say that the code is running in CentOS-linux, AFAIK SQLSRV-driver is Windows only?

Comment: [Linux and macOS Installation Tutorial for the Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Thak you, I'll check it

Comment: Hmmm, things are getting even more interesting... This program uses two databases which both happen to have table Users (one for app, another for  authentication) - both residing the same database server but different databases. For the app table things work just the way they used, but for the authentication database not...

Answer (score 1):

Seems, it was sort of privileges error after the database migration. I removed the user that had come from restore operation and granted correct privileges again. Only, I am quite positive, I had done it already once. And I think there was no login errors when trying to use the database.

Sorry for dumb question. Though, I have always said, that there are no dumb questions, just dumb askers...

hank

Comment: Perhaps this time you will document the requirements and installation processes needed to install your development and production environments. That is an **essential** part of disaster recovery - but only part. It is concerning that you only just recently "discovered" the use of two databases. Perhaps you have an "orphaned user" issue (a term you can search) - but I would expect a very different error for that. Maybe this exposes a flaw in the app error handling that should be addressed as well.